# Easy way to keep track of the change of variables in a java program without the use of an external debugger

Tags: java

So I created a class that I can include inside my programs class's and start with a `Thread` that will basically alert me whenever certain variables change. I am wondering if anyone has any better ideas to quickly and efficiently get this kind of information and if not if they have any suggestions for this class. FYI the `alert()` method is basically a simple System.out.println().

```
public class OutputState extends Thread{

  String   className = this.getClass().toString().replace("class ","").replace("$OutputState",""); 
  String[] desc = {"canvasWidth","canvasHeight","relativeCenterX","relativeCenterY","zoom","hAdjust","vAdjust"};
  int[]    delay = {0,0,99,99,0,0,0,};
  Object[] var;
  int maxDescLength = 0;

  public void init(){
     Object[] v = {canvasWidth,canvasHeight,relativeCenterX,relativeCenterY,zoom,hAdjust,vAdjust};
     var = v;
  }

  public void run(){
     init();
     while(true){
        boolean newLine = false;
        Object[] v = {canvasWidth,canvasHeight,relativeCenterX,relativeCenterY,zoom,hAdjust,vAdjust};
        for(int i = 0; i < var.length; i++){
           if(maxDescLength < desc[i].length()){
              maxDescLength = desc[i].length();
           }
           if(!var[i].equals(v[i])){
              var[i]=v[i];
              String spaces = " ";
              int count = desc[i].length()+1;
              while(count <= maxDescLength){
                 spaces += " ";
                 count++;
              }
              alert(className + "." + desc[i] + spaces + "= " + var[i]);
              newLine = true;
              if(delay[i] > 0){try{Thread.sleep(delay[i]);}catch(InterruptedException e){}}
           }
        }
        if(newLine){
           alert("------------------------------------");
        }
        try{Thread.sleep(1);}catch(InterruptedException e){}
     }   
  }
}
```

The basic concept is that `v` is set to the variables you want to keep track of and will continue to update itself with the changing variables in the program and `var` will contain what `OutputState` last knew they were. Whenever anything in `v` changes `var` will catch it and output the custom message. I know many people would find something like this useful which leads me to believe that there are probably better ways that I haven't found yet out there. I would greatly appreciate any input!

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj thanks a lot! That is a very interesting concept that I've never heard of before. Will definitely look into it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not an easy way to accomplish what you're trying to do.
Even if you loop (like you're currently doing), you will not only slow the rest of the computation down (due to bus traffic), but might also miss some updates (if the monitor thread gets scheduled less often or on a busier processor than the worker thread).

Like it was noted in the comments, you should better use some Aspect-oriented programming Language, or Java proxies, or a simpler delegate pattern. Either way, you might need modifications to your existing code.

```
interface IWorkState {
    //Declares the method of WorkState
}

class WorkState implements IWorkState {
    //Whatever java bean
}

class WorkTask implements Runnable {
    private final IWorkState state;

    public void addStateObserver(IWorkState initialState) {
         state = initialState
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Task instructions here
        //instructions should operate on the state variable
    }
}

class VarMonitor {
    public void update(Object changed) {
        //subject has changed, react to it
        eventQueue.submit(/* a Runnable that handles the state change,
                           with embedded information about the change */);

    }
}

class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final VarMonitor mon = new VarMonitor();
        WorkTask t = new WorkTask(Proxy.newProxyInstance(getClass().getClassLoader(), new Class[] {IWorkState.class}, new InvocationHandler() {
            private final WorkState realWorkState = new WorkState();
            Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) {
                Object res = method.invoke(realWorkState, args);
                //An annotation would work better
                if (method.getName().substring(0,3).equals("set")) {
                    mon.update(this);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

A third option is to use subclasses of `java.util.Observable` and, of course, an observer pattern.
Something like:

```
class WorkState extends java.util.Observable {
    //A thread-safe observable java bean
}

class WorkTask implements Runnable {
    private final WorkState state = new WorkState();

    public void addStateObserver(Observer ob) {
         state.addObserver(ob);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Task instructions here
        //instructions should operate on the state variable
    }
}

class VarMonitor implements Observer {
    private final ExecutorService eventQueue
            = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    @Override
    public void update(Observable subject, Object info) {
        //subject has changed, react to it
        eventQueue.submit(/* a Runnable that handles the state change,
                           with embedded information about the change */);

    }
}
```

if you're using this pattern with immutable objects, you can easily implement an ObservableReference class, which will work for all of your objects.

PS: I didn't mention it before, but multithreaded access to shared variables must be synchronized, or the variables must be either thread-safe or volatile. You can't blindly poll shared variables, or you might get some result wrong (such as seeing partially updated objects).

Comment: Noted, I'm definitely looking into AOP and from what I've read it sounds pretty promising albeit maybe just a little more robust than what I'm looking for. This particular class is working fine as we speak and is helping so part of me wants to improve it for the sake of excitement and the other half of me wants to share it as well. The secret pessimistic third half of me wants people to tell me why it's idiotic :p thanks for the answer though I'm definitely going to look into the AOP way of doing things and see if it fits my typical design pattern.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to *reliably* tell when a variable changes is to declare it as `private` and only change it via a setter method.  Then you write the `setter` so that it tests to see whether each call is going to change the variable's state.

For example:

```
private int summit;

public void setSummit(int value) {
    if (value != summit) {
        System.err.println("Ey up: summit's changed!");
    }
}
```

If the variable's type is an array, it is going to be impossible to reliably tell when array elements change ... unless you hide the array from direct access.

---

If you are willing to use AOP or some other form of code injection, you may be able to do this kind of thing without modifying your source code.  But at runtime, you will effectively doing the above.

Comment: I understand that and I do declare pretty much everything that I can as private. However for logic testing and debugging across different classes I wanted a way to have both classes describe the changing parts about themselves when they happen. This way I can see what's synchronized and what's not without having to drop a ton of debugging messages in every method of my classes.

Comment: Not withstanding that, the way you are proposing to monitor variables is unreliable.

Comment: I can see that and definitely know why as well. It's a level of unreliability that I'm okay with though. It doesn't need to be 100% verbose. Just an At-a-glance update while debugging without the need of a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

For each bean that contains properties you would like to track you could add PropertyChangeSupport and a method to add a PropertyChangeListener to it.  Then in the setters you call firePropertyChange on the PropertyChangeSupport.  With this configuration you could even use configuration to decide which objects you want to listen to and dynamically add and remove listeners as needed.  You wouldn't need a separate thread and you wouldn't need the looping and sleeping.  Here's a small sample that demonstrates.

```
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport;

public class ChangeTest {

  private String val1;
  private String val2;
  private PropertyChangeSupport pcs = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

  public String getVal1() {
    return val1;
  }

  public void setVal1(String val1) {
    pcs.firePropertyChange("val1", this.val1, val1);
    this.val1 = val1;
  }

  public String getVal2() {
    return val2;
  }

  public void setVal2(String val2) {
    pcs.firePropertyChange("val2", this.val2, val2);
    this.val2 = val2;
  }

  public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener ) {
    pcs.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
  }

  public static void main( String[] args ) {
    ChangeTest test = new ChangeTest();
    test.addPropertyChangeListener(new Listener());
    for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
      test.setVal1("value " + i );
      test.setVal2(test.getVal1() + test.getVal1());
    }
  }

  public static class Listener implements PropertyChangeListener {

    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
  System.out.println( evt.getPropertyName() + " changed from '" + evt.getOldValue() + "' to '" + evt.getNewValue() + "'" );
    }
  }
}
```

Output from that program is:

```
val1 changed from 'null' to 'value 0'
val2 changed from 'null' to 'value 0value 0'
val1 changed from 'value 0' to 'value 1'
val2 changed from 'value 0value 0' to 'value 1value 1'
val1 changed from 'value 1' to 'value 2'
val2 changed from 'value 1value 1' to 'value 2value 2'
val1 changed from 'value 2' to 'value 3'
val2 changed from 'value 2value 2' to 'value 3value 3'
val1 changed from 'value 3' to 'value 4'
val2 changed from 'value 3value 3' to 'value 4value 4'
```

Comment: This is a very interesting way to accomplish this. The only issue is that I would have is that I have to use setter's to internally modify my local variables. That isn't necessarily a big sacrifice though when designing future `Objects` but would be a minor nightmare for my current program :p thanks a lot!

Comment: Generally you are better off using setters for modification anyway, even internally just to avoid something like this being a minor nightmare in the future. You'll have the same requirement on setters with AOP. In any case, good luck :)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I have the feeling it's a better practice all around but I have no basis for that quite yet besides this. I appreciate your help.